# Stack two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a simple data and I want to merge two columns but in a specific way. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to resolve my problem even if it looks pretty simple.
So my data looks like something like this:

```
Numbers Groups   
  1      A   
  2      A   
  3      B   
  4      C   
  5      C
```

In the end, I want to have something like this:

```
1  
2   
A   
3   
B   
4   
5   
C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"Numbers Groups
1 A
2 A
3 B
4 C
5 C")

unlist(lapply(split(d, d$Groups), function(x) c(x$Numbers, as.character(x$Groups[1]))))
#  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  C1  C2  C3 
# "1" "2" "A" "3" "B" "4" "5" "C"
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that `Numbers` are unique then,

```
v1 <- c(t(df4))
v1[!duplicated(v1, fromLast = T)]
#[1] "1" "2" "A" "3" "B" "4" "5" "C"
```

If there are duplicated `Numbers`, (lets say `Numbers = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5)`)then we can `transform` and `make.unique` prior to concatenating. `sub` can be used to remove decimals from `make.unique`
(Using the `unique` approach mentioned by @Jaap in comments just to get everything in one go),

```
sub('\\..*' ,'',unique(c(t(transform(df4, numbers = make.unique(as.character(numbers))))), 
                                                                          fromLast = TRUE))
#[1] "1" "1" "A" "3" "B" "4" "5" "C"
```

Comment: That is a pretty strong assumption as long as OP hasn't specified it

Comment: @docendodiscimus true.

Comment: @Sotos so many ways to do it. I have been learning R for about 2 years and it is so frustrating when I can't deal with such an easy task.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map`

```
lst <- split(df1$Numbers, df1$Groups)
unlist(Map(`c`, lst, names(lst)), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "1" "2" "A" "3" "B" "4" "5" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

A fifth approach:

```
d2 <- aggregate(V1 ~ V2, d, paste0, collapse = ',')

strsplit(do.call(paste, c(d2[2:1], sep = ',', collapse = ',')),',')[[1]]
```

which gives:

```
[1] "1"  "2"  "A"  "33" "B"  "4"  "5"  "C"
```

In respons to @docendodiscimus' comment: the updated solution also works when the numbers consist of more than one digit & also when the number are not unique within each group.

---

Used data:

```
d <- read.table(text="1 A
2 A
2 A
33 B
4 C
5 C", header=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `sapply`. For every unique value of `V1` extract its corresponding values and combine them together using `c`.

```
unlist(sapply(unique(df$V2), function(x) c(df$V1[df$V2 %in% x], x),
                                                        USE.NAMES = FALSE))

#[1] "1" "2" "A" "3" "B" "4" "5" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 100% `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  summarize(output= list(c(Numbers,Groups[1]))) %>%
  unnest(output) %>%
  pull(output)

# [1] "1" "2" "A" "3" "B" "4" "5" "C"
```

My shortest:

```
unname(unlist(t(nest(df,Numbers)[2:1]))
```

And finally my own 100% base solutions:

```
with(aggregate(Numbers ~ Groups,df,list),unlist(Map(c,Numbers,Groups),use.names = F))
```

Or

```
unlist(by(df,df$Groups,function(x) c(x$Numbers,x$Groups[1])),use.names = F)
```